# UML Activity Diagram Object Flow/ Parameter

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

In this Activity Diagram, I'm using an input-pin for some user parameter which need to be passed to the other activity (some_activity). I also want to use those parameters in the "param_test" diagram (guard of the decision node). Is this the correct syntax?

[image: seq-diag]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that UML defines exactly what can be used as a guard,  but the reader of the model will probably understand what your model, so I would say it is correct